# Java regex not matching (russian)

Tags: java, regex

Trying to match a string "Манихина Галина Владимировна" and others of the same format. That is, a proper name with three words. I'm new to regex and am not sure what's wrong with my statement.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String temp = "Манихина Галина Владимировна";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[а-я]+\\s[а-я]+\\s[а-я]+$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
        if (matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) documentation regexp does not match unicode:

> By default, case-insensitive matching assumes that only characters in the US-ASCII charset are being matched

In order to make your code working, add [UNICODE_CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) flag:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[а-я]+\\s[а-я]+\\s[а-я]+$",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Java by default doesn't properly match unicode text when using character classes: ( `\\s`  in your code). You have to use [UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) in order to use predefined classes like the whitespace character class you used in your pattern.
So working Pattern.compile usage would be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[а-я]+\\s[а-я]+\\s[а-я]+$",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

When you add UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS, you also imply using [UNICODE_CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) flag - which is necessary for CASE_INSENSITIVE flag to work with unicode characters

Answer (score -1):

This pattern should work:

```
^[A-Я][а-я]+\s[A-Я][а-я]+\s[A-Я][а-я]+$
```

There were two problems with your pattern:

- You didn't include capital letters from the alphabet;
- `\\s` matches a backslash, then a space, when (I assume) you only wanted to match the space.

Comment: The pattern is compiled with `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag and `\\s` is just how you have to write `\s` in a string literal.